# value del submit no se muestra al completo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario con un botón `submit` que tiene un texto. Ese texto es demasiado largo y a ciertas resoluciones no se ve bien. El texto es irremediablemente este:

```css
.divSumit {
  padding-left: 50px !important;
  padding-right: 50px !important;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="final">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox" required>Acepto recibir comunicaciones de EmpresaEjemplo, así como su política de privacidad.</a></label>
  </div>

  <div class="divSumit">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" href="http://enlace.com" class="submit" value="HAZ CLICK EN ESTE BOTÓN Y PIDE TU DVD" name="submit" id="submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que entre todo el texto en el botón de `submit`?

Comment: Si estas usando bootstrap, ¿por qué no usas sus [botones](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los 50 pixeles de `padding-left` y de `padding-right`, sumados a la elevada longitud del texto del `<input type="submit">` ocasiona que termine por salirse del **layout** en tamaños de dispositivos estrechos.

Una alternativa es sustituir el `<input type="submit">` por un `<button type="submit">` ya que este permite que el texto de dentro se adapte para ocupar varias filas en caso de que no tenga espacio para ocupar solamente una y además también lanza el formulario, como un `<input type="submit">`.

```css
.divSumit {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 50px !important;
  padding-right: 50px !important;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="final">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox" required>Acepto recibir comunicaciones de EmpresaEjemplo, así como su política de privacidad.</a></label>
  </div>

  <div class="divSumit">
    <button class="submit" type="submit" href="http://enlace.com" class="submit" name="submit" id="submit">HAZ CLICK EN ESTE BOTÓN Y PIDE TU DVD</button>
  </div>
</div>
```